# SQL query ordering wrong, not sure why

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, sorting

```
SELECT a.[Evaluation Number], a.[CSO Name], a.service
    , a.[Date of call], a.[Name of Monitor]
    , a.[Date Sheet Completed]
FROM [KD call monitoring] AS a
WHERE a.[Evaluation Number]  
    IN (SELECT TOP 1 [Evaluation Number]     
        FROM [KD call monitoring] b     
        WHERE b.[CSO Name] = a.[CSO Name]            
            AND b.[Date of Call] =                
               (SELECT MAX([date of call])                 
                FROM [KD call monitoring]                 
                WHERE [cso name] = a.[CSO Name])     
                ORDER  BY [Evaluation Number]);
```

this is the code i have on my call evaluation database at work, it is ordering the entries so i know which employee has not had their calls monitored for a while. however it orders fine from 31st jan up until the end of febuary (about halfway down the list) then just places random peoples entries before settling down and giving me the most recent person and entry that has been evaluated.
this list only needs to show one entry per person - the latest one.
im not sure if its messing up because of the leap year or something but i have no idea how to fix it!
im using ACCESS XP. and i would attach an image however im a new user so not allowed!

Comment: You don't seem to have an `ORDER BY` on your outer-most query so the final resultset will not be ordered.

Comment: Add ORDER BY a.[Date of call] to the outer query, as @creamyegg says.

Comment: @creamyegg. Post this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't seem to have an `ORDER BY` on your outer-most query so the final resultset will not be ordered.